# reactにおけるprocessのエラー

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-jsx

現在，reactを用いて，Webサイト開発を行っているものです．
コード内でnedbを用いてデータベースを構築しています．コマンドラインで，$ node "path名"として，実行すると可能なのですが，localhost:3000の方で見ると，以下のエラーが発生しています．

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
process is not defined
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ./node_modules/path/path.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37516:17)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81477:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80900:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81134:21)
    at ./node_modules/nedb/lib/persistence.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35644:10)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81477:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80900:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81134:21)
    at ./node_modules/nedb/lib/datastore.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33587:17)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81477:31)
```

多くのサイトを見てみるとwebpack.config.jsをいじることで解決すると書かれているのですが，create-react-appで作ったのが原因なのかこのファイルが見つかりません．
どなたかこのエラーの解決策についてご教示ください．　よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました．[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561200/how-to-fix-process-in-react/76570073#76570073)よりご参照ください．pathをuninstallすることや，webpack.config.jsを編集することが必要でした．